# How to run elixir script through `launch.json` file in vscode?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I want to run script for developing function.

My `mirror_a.exs` is as follows:

```
IO.inspect("hellworlda")
```

In the bash terminal, the command mix run "lib/mirror_a.ex" output is as follows:

```
macbook:mirror yuchen$ mix run "lib/mirror_a.exs"
"hellworlda"
```

In the vscode, the launch.json is as follows:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "mix_task",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "mix run",
        "task": "lib/mirror_a.exs",
        "taskArgs": [],
        "projectDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
]
```

When run debugging mode, no output, why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The launch.json file should be adjusted as follows:

```
{
    "type": "mix_task",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "mix run",
    "task": "run",
    "taskArgs": ["lib/mirror_a.exs"],
    "projectDir": "${workspaceRoot}"
},
```

In addition, the reason of "the output is empty" is that right corner's filter select box. It should be set to related `launch.json`'s part. Otherwise the output may be empty.